# How to display path bar in Files on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 and is great. There are missing things, like seeing the path bar in Files. How can I enable it to permanently view it?

[image]

Comment: ctrl+l (l in language).. did you try that?

Comment: that works when you click the top. But can you have something to view it permanently?

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true`

Comment: @PRATAP, that is obviously the answer, so go ahead and post it as an answer. I'll upvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to enable it permanently use the below command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true
```

[image]

to disable it,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry false
```